# Java - multiple JLabels to one single JPanel

Tags: java, swing, icons, jpanel, jlabel

I am currently reading from my database where i am able to read the location strings and convert them to images that are able to appear on a jframe. I create a JLabel and then change this to an ImageIcon. The code for that is below. How do I put all of these imageicons into one single JPanel. So far, I have only been able to put the image into a separate JPanel and all of these jpanels appear on a jframe as the method iterates over every image that is matched in the database.. Any help would be appreciated

```
JLabel image = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(pic));

image.setIcon(new ImageIcon(pic));

panel.add(image);
```

Comment: Why can't you just call `panel.add` for each image? What breaks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since a `JPanel` by default uses a `FlowLayout`, you can just use subsequent `add` calls

```
panel.add( image1 );
panel.add( image2 );
panel.add( image3 );
```

and all images will be added to the panel